# Создать файл RTF из кастомной формы asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Задача такая: есть форма, на ней разные поля(строки и таблица), мне нужно сохранить эту форму на диск в файле в формате RTF. Подскажите, как это сделать?
Я вижу, как то через RichTextBox, но мне не подходит этот вариант.

Comment: `мне не подходит этот вариант` - почему?

Comment: Ну я не уверен, что следует добавлять ссылку на WinForms, в любом случае на форму точно добавлять нельзя

Comment: Ну так поищите, как html в pdf сохранить. Способов много - от полной генерации документа до заполнения готового шаблона.

Comment: то есть сохранять в pdf, а потом в rtf?

Comment: Ой, опечатался, да, rtf, кстати, зачем вам rtf? Pdf не подходит? Почему?

Comment: Идите на [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=rtf) и выбирайте подходящую библиотеку.